# How to uninstall REMIX IDE completely from Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS?

Tags: software-center, uninstall, software-uninstall

I have installed REMIX IDE i.e. an ide for programming in Solidity programming language(widely used in Blockchain technology). I have installed it using it's official website. Now I want to uninstall it completely. Please help me how to uninstall it completely?

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: I installed it using it's official github repo - https://github.com/ethereum/remix-desktop/releases 
You can check this link.

Comment: So did you use a deb file?

Comment: yes i used the deb file

Answer (score 1):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt purge remix-ide
```

Comment: did you mean remix instead of redmix?

Comment: It was a typo. Fixed.